# Speed up an integration function in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy, optimization

I have a function that is the inner loop of some larger problem. SO it will be called millions of time. I have tried to optimize it. But since it is my first numerical project, I am wondering if there are other ways that can improve the speed.

cython does not seem to help. Maybe numpy is close to c already.
or I don't write cython code efficiently.

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import numexpr as ne


par_mu_rho = 0.8
par_alpha_rho = 0.7
# ' the first two are mean of mus and the '
# ' last two are the mean of alphas.'
cov_epsilon = [[1, par_mu_rho], [par_mu_rho, 1]]
cov_nu = [[1, par_alpha_rho], [par_alpha_rho, 1]]
nrows = 10000 
np.random.seed(123)
epsilon_sim = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], cov_epsilon, nrows)
nu_sim = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 0], cov_nu, nrows)
errors = np.concatenate((epsilon_sim, nu_sim), axis=1)
errors = np.exp(errors)


### the function to be optimized

def mktout(mean_mu_alpha, errors, par_gamma):
    mu10 = errors[:, 0] * math.exp(mean_mu_alpha[0])
    mu11 = math.exp(par_gamma) * mu10  # mu with gamma
    mu20 = errors[:, 1] * math.exp(mean_mu_alpha[1])
    mu21 = math.exp(par_gamma) * mu20
    alpha1 = errors[:, 2] * math.exp(mean_mu_alpha[2])
    alpha2 = errors[:, 3] * math.exp(mean_mu_alpha[3])

    j_is_larger = (mu10 > mu20)
    #     useneither1 = (mu10 < 1/168)
    threshold2 = (1 + mu10 * alpha1) / (168 + alpha1)
    #     useboth1 = (mu21 >= threshold2)
    j_is_smaller = ~j_is_larger
    #     useneither2 = (mu20 < 1/168)
    threshold3 = (1 + mu20 * alpha2) / (168 + alpha2)
    #     useboth2 = (mu11 >= threshold3)
    case1 = j_is_larger * (mu10 < 1 / 168)
    case2 = j_is_larger * (mu21 >= threshold2)
    #     case3 = j_is_larger * (1 - (useneither1 | useboth1))
    case3 = j_is_larger ^ (case1 | case2)
    case4 = j_is_smaller * (mu20 < 1 / 168)
    case5 = j_is_smaller * (mu11 >= threshold3)
    #     case6 = j_is_smaller * (1 - (useneither2 | useboth2))
    case6 = j_is_smaller ^ (case4 | case5)
    t0 = ne.evaluate(
        "case1*168+case2 * (168 + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) +case3 / threshold2 +case4 * 168 +case5 * (168 + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) + case6 / threshold3")
    # for some cases, t1 would be 0 anyway, so they are omitted here.
    t1 = ne.evaluate(
        "case2 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1) +case3 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu10 - alpha1) +case5 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)")
    # t2 = (j_is_larger*useboth1*(t0*alpha2*mu21- alpha2) +
    #       j_is_smaller*useboth2*(t0*alpha2*mu21- alpha2) +
    #       j_is_smaller*(1- (useneither2|useboth2))*(t0*alpha2*mu20 - alpha2)
    #       )
    t2 = 168 - t0 - t1
    p12 = case2 + case5
    p1 = case3 + p12
    p2 = case6 + p12
    return t1.sum()/10000, t2.sum()/10000, p1.sum()/10000, p2.sum()/10000

timeit mktout([-6,-6,-1,-1], errors, -0.7)
```

On my old mac with 2.2GHz i7. the function runs at about 200µs.

**Updates:**

Based on suggestions and code from @CodeSurgeon and @GZ0, I settled on the following code

```py
def mktout_full(double[:] mean_mu_alpha, double[:, ::1] errors, double par_gamma):
    cdef:
        size_t i, n
        double[4] exp
        double exp_par_gamma
        double mu10, mu11, mu20, mu21
        double alpha1, alpha2
        double threshold2, threshold3
        double t0, t1, t2
        double t1_sum, t2_sum, p1_sum, p2_sum, p12_sum
        double c

    #compute the exp outside of the loop
    n = errors.shape[0]
    exp[0] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[0])
    exp[1] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[1])
    exp[2] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[2])
    exp[3] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[3])
    exp_par_gamma = cmath.exp(par_gamma)
    c = 168.0

    t1_sum = 0.0
    t2_sum = 0.0
    p1_sum = 0.0
    p2_sum = 0.0
    p12_sum = 0.0

    for i in range(n) :
        mu10 = errors[i, 0] * exp[0]
    #         mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
        mu20 = errors[i, 1] * exp[1]
    #         mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
    #         alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
    #         alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]
    #         j_is_larger = mu10 > mu20
    #         j_is_smaller = not j_is_larger

        if (mu10 >= mu20):
            if (mu10 >= 1/c) :
                mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
                alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
                alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]
                threshold2 = (1 + mu10 * alpha1) / (c + alpha1)
                if (mu21 >= threshold2):
                    mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
                    t0 =  (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2)
                    t1 = (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)
                    t1_sum += t1
                    t2_sum += c - t0 - t1
                    p1_sum += 1
                    p2_sum += 1
                    p12_sum += 1
                else :
                    t1_sum += ((1/threshold2) * alpha1 * mu10 - alpha1)
                    p1_sum += 1
        else :
            if (mu20 >= 1/c) :
                mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
                alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
                alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]
                threshold3 = (1 + mu20 * alpha2) / (c + alpha2)
                if (mu11 >= threshold3):
                    mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
                    t0 =  (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2)
                    t1 = (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)
                    t1_sum += t1
                    t2_sum += c - t0 - t1
                    p1_sum += 1
                    p2_sum += 1
                    p12_sum += 1
                else :
                    t2_sum += ((1/threshold3) * alpha2 * mu20 - alpha2)
                    p2_sum += 1

    return t1_sum/n, t2_sum/n, p1_sum/n, p2_sum/n, p12_sum/n
```

my original code runs at 650µs.
`mktout` and `mktout_if` by codesurgeon run at about 220µs and 120µs.
the above `mktout_full` runs at about 68 µs.
What I do in `mktout_full` is to optimize the if-else logic in `mktout_if`.
Perhaps surprisingly, parallelized `out_loop` by codesurgeon combined with if-else logic in `mktout_full` is way slower (121ms).

Comment: 200us is a long time? what's your input data volume, and what's your expected performance, of if it worth the effort of optimizing. seems you are just checking the math function but no acutal usage ?

Comment: As far as optimization goes I would take a look at your outer loops & see if they are necessary. It maybe that there is a [Scipy intergation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) function that can do what `mktout()` is doing?

Comment: I tried scipy's integrate.nquad. It take seconds to do so primarily due to the varying limits.

Comment: There are three levels of optimizations. The above function (with some modification) will be the objective function in the most inner loop. The second loop currently run at 1~2 minutes. An optimistic estimate for the outer loop would be  more than 100 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly looking at the code and attempting to cythonize it, simply adding ndarray types to all of the parameters and variables does not change performance meaningfully. If you are fighting for shaving off microseconds for this function in this tight inner loop, I would consider making the following modifications:

1. The reason why this code is so tough to cythonize is that your code is vectorized. All of the operations are going through `numpy` or `numexpr`. **While each of these operations alone are efficient, they all add some python overhead** (which can be seen if you look at the annotated `.html` files cython can produce).
2. If you are calling this function many times (as it appears based on your comments), you can save some time by making `mktout` a `cdef` function instead. **Python function calls have significant overhead.**
3. Minor but you can try avoiding any functions from python's `math` module. You can replace this with `from libc cimport math as cmath` and use `cmath.exp` instead.
4. I see your `mktout` function takes in a python list `mean_mu_alpha`. You could consider using a `cdef class` object to replace this parameter and type this instead. If you choose to make `mktout` a `cdef` function instead, this can become just a struct or `double *` array. Either way, indexing into a python list (which can be contain arbitrary python objects that need to be unboxed into corresponds c-types) is going to be slow.
5. **This is probably the most important part.** For each call to `mktout`, you are allocating memory for lots of arrays (for each `mu`, `alpha`, `threshold`, `case`, `t-` and `p-` array). You then proceed to free all of this memory at the end of the function (through python's gc), only to likely use all of this space again the next call. If you can change the signature of `mktout`, you can pass in all of these arrays as parameters so that **the memory can be reused and overwritten across function calls**. Another option, which is better for this case, would be to **iterate through the array and do all of the calculations one element at a time.**
6. You can multithread the code using cython's `prange` function. I would reach for this after you have made all of the above changes, and I would do the multithreading outside of the `mktout` function itself. That is, you would be multithreading **calls to mktout** rather than multithreading `mktout` itself.

Making the above changes will be a lot of work, and you will likely have to reimplement many of the functions provided by numpy and numexpr yourself to avoid the python overhead associated with each of time. Please let me know if any part of this is unclear.

---

**Update #1:** Implementing points #1, #3, and #5, I get about a **11x fold speed-up**. Here is what this code looks like. I am sure it can go faster if you ditch the `def` function, the `list mean_mu_alpha` input, and the `tuple` output. **Note: I get slightly different results in the last decimal place compared to the original code, likely due to some floating point rules I do not understand.**

```
from libc cimport math as cmath
from libc.stdint cimport *
from libc.stdlib cimport *

def mktout(list mean_mu_alpha, double[:, ::1] errors, double par_gamma):
    cdef:
        size_t i, n
        double[4] exp
        double exp_par_gamma
        double mu10, mu11, mu20, mu21
        double alpha1, alpha2
        bint j_is_larger, j_is_smaller
        double threshold2, threshold3
        bint case1, case2, case3, case4, case5, case6
        double t0, t1, t2
        double p12, p1, p2
        double t1_sum, t2_sum, p1_sum, p2_sum
        double c

    #compute the exp outside of the loop
    n = errors.shape[0]
    exp[0] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[0])
    exp[1] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[1])
    exp[2] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[2])
    exp[3] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[3])
    exp_par_gamma = cmath.exp(par_gamma)
    c = 168.0

    t1_sum = 0.0
    t2_sum = 0.0
    p1_sum = 0.0
    p2_sum = 0.0

    for i in range(n):
        mu10 = errors[i, 0] * exp[0]
        mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
        mu20 = errors[i, 1] * exp[1]
        mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
        alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
        alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]

        j_is_larger = mu10 > mu20
        j_is_smaller = not j_is_larger
        threshold2 = (1 + mu10 * alpha1) / (c + alpha1)
        threshold3 = (1 + mu20 * alpha2) / (c + alpha2)

        case1 = j_is_larger * (mu10 < 1 / c)
        case2 = j_is_larger * (mu21 >= threshold2)
        case3 = j_is_larger ^ (case1 | case2)
        case4 = j_is_smaller * (mu20 < 1 / c)
        case5 = j_is_smaller * (mu11 >= threshold3)
        case6 = j_is_smaller ^ (case4 | case5)

        t0 = case1*c+case2 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) +case3 / threshold2 +case4 * c +case5 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) + case6 / threshold3
        t1 = case2 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1) +case3 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu10 - alpha1) +case5 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)
        t2 = c - t0 - t1

        p12 = case2 + case5
        p1 = case3 + p12
        p2 = case6 + p12

        t1_sum += t1
        t2_sum += t2
        p1_sum += p1
        p2_sum += p2

    return t1_sum/n, t2_sum/n, p1_sum/n, p2_sum/n
```

---

**Update #2:** Implemented the `cdef` (#2), python object elimination (#4) and the multithreading (#6) ideas. #2 and #4 alone had negligible benefit, but were necessary for #6 since the GIL cannot be accessed in OpenMP `prange` loops. With the multithreading, you get an additional 2.5x speed boost on my quad core laptop, amounting to code that is about 27.5x faster than the original. My `outer_loop` function is not wholly accurate though since it just recalculates the same result over and over, but it should be enough for a test case. The complete code is below:

```
from libc cimport math as cmath
from libc.stdint cimport *
from libc.stdlib cimport *
from cython.parallel cimport prange

def mktout(list mean_mu_alpha, double[:, ::1] errors, double par_gamma):
    cdef:
        size_t i, n
        double[4] exp
        double exp_par_gamma
        double mu10, mu11, mu20, mu21
        double alpha1, alpha2
        bint j_is_larger, j_is_smaller
        double threshold2, threshold3
        bint case1, case2, case3, case4, case5, case6
        double t0, t1, t2
        double p12, p1, p2
        double t1_sum, t2_sum, p1_sum, p2_sum
        double c

    #compute the exp outside of the loop
    n = errors.shape[0]
    exp[0] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[0])
    exp[1] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[1])
    exp[2] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[2])
    exp[3] = cmath.exp(<double>mean_mu_alpha[3])
    exp_par_gamma = cmath.exp(par_gamma)
    c = 168.0

    t1_sum = 0.0
    t2_sum = 0.0
    p1_sum = 0.0
    p2_sum = 0.0

    for i in range(n):
        mu10 = errors[i, 0] * exp[0]
        mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
        mu20 = errors[i, 1] * exp[1]
        mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
        alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
        alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]

        j_is_larger = mu10 > mu20
        j_is_smaller = not j_is_larger
        threshold2 = (1 + mu10 * alpha1) / (c + alpha1)
        threshold3 = (1 + mu20 * alpha2) / (c + alpha2)

        case1 = j_is_larger * (mu10 < 1 / c)
        case2 = j_is_larger * (mu21 >= threshold2)
        case3 = j_is_larger ^ (case1 | case2)
        case4 = j_is_smaller * (mu20 < 1 / c)
        case5 = j_is_smaller * (mu11 >= threshold3)
        case6 = j_is_smaller ^ (case4 | case5)

        t0 = case1*c+case2 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) +case3 / threshold2 +case4 * c +case5 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) + case6 / threshold3
        t1 = case2 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1) +case3 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu10 - alpha1) +case5 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)
        t2 = c - t0 - t1

        p12 = case2 + case5
        p1 = case3 + p12
        p2 = case6 + p12

        t1_sum += t1
        t2_sum += t2
        p1_sum += p1
        p2_sum += p2

    return t1_sum/n, t2_sum/n, p1_sum/n, p2_sum/n

ctypedef struct Vec4:
    double a
    double b
    double c
    double d

def outer_loop(list mean_mu_alpha, double[:, ::1] errors, double par_gamma, size_t n):
    cdef:
        size_t i
        Vec4 mean_vec
        Vec4 out

    mean_vec.a = <double>(mean_mu_alpha[0])
    mean_vec.b = <double>(mean_mu_alpha[1])
    mean_vec.c = <double>(mean_mu_alpha[2])
    mean_vec.d = <double>(mean_mu_alpha[3])

    with nogil:
        for i in prange(n):
            cy_mktout(&out, &mean_vec, errors, par_gamma)
    return out

cdef void cy_mktout(Vec4 *out, Vec4 *mean_mu_alpha, double[:, ::1] errors, double par_gamma) nogil:
    cdef:
        size_t i, n
        double[4] exp
        double exp_par_gamma
        double mu10, mu11, mu20, mu21
        double alpha1, alpha2
        bint j_is_larger, j_is_smaller
        double threshold2, threshold3
        bint case1, case2, case3, case4, case5, case6
        double t0, t1, t2
        double p12, p1, p2
        double t1_sum, t2_sum, p1_sum, p2_sum
        double c

    #compute the exp outside of the loop
    n = errors.shape[0]
    exp[0] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.a)
    exp[1] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.b)
    exp[2] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.c)
    exp[3] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.d)
    exp_par_gamma = cmath.exp(par_gamma)
    c = 168.0

    t1_sum = 0.0
    t2_sum = 0.0
    p1_sum = 0.0
    p2_sum = 0.0

    for i in range(n):
        mu10 = errors[i, 0] * exp[0]
        mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
        mu20 = errors[i, 1] * exp[1]
        mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
        alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
        alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]

        j_is_larger = mu10 > mu20
        j_is_smaller = not j_is_larger
        threshold2 = (1 + mu10 * alpha1) / (c + alpha1)
        threshold3 = (1 + mu20 * alpha2) / (c + alpha2)

        case1 = j_is_larger * (mu10 < 1 / c)
        case2 = j_is_larger * (mu21 >= threshold2)
        case3 = j_is_larger ^ (case1 | case2)
        case4 = j_is_smaller * (mu20 < 1 / c)
        case5 = j_is_smaller * (mu11 >= threshold3)
        case6 = j_is_smaller ^ (case4 | case5)

        t0 = case1*c+case2 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) +case3 / threshold2 +case4 * c +case5 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) + case6 / threshold3
        t1 = case2 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1) +case3 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu10 - alpha1) +case5 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)
        t2 = c - t0 - t1

        p12 = case2 + case5
        p1 = case3 + p12
        p2 = case6 + p12

        t1_sum += t1
        t2_sum += t2
        p1_sum += p1
        p2_sum += p2

    out.a = t1_sum/n
    out.b = t2_sum/n
    out.c = p1_sum/n
    out.d = p2_sum/n
```

And the `setup.py` file that I use is as follows (has all of the optimization and OpenMP flags):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.core import Extension
import numpy as np
import os
import shutil
import platform

libraries = {
    "Linux": [],
    "Windows": [],
}
language = "c"
args = ["-w", "-std=c11", "-O3", "-ffast-math", "-march=native", "-fopenmp"]
link_args = ["-std=c11", "-fopenmp"]

annotate = True
directives = {
    "binding": True,
    "boundscheck": False,
    "wraparound": False,
    "initializedcheck": False,
    "cdivision": True,
    "nonecheck": False,
    "language_level": "3",
    #"c_string_type": "unicode",
    #"c_string_encoding": "utf-8",
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    system = platform.system()
    libs = libraries[system]
    extensions = []
    ext_modules = []

    #create extensions
    for path, dirs, file_names in os.walk("."):
        for file_name in file_names:
            if file_name.endswith("pyx"):
                ext_path = "{0}/{1}".format(path, file_name)
                ext_name = ext_path \
                    .replace("./", "") \
                    .replace("/", ".") \
                    .replace(".pyx", "")
                ext = Extension(
                    name=ext_name, 
                    sources=[ext_path], 
                    libraries=libs,
                    language=language,
                    extra_compile_args=args,
                    extra_link_args=link_args,
                    include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
                )
                extensions.append(ext)

    #setup all extensions
    ext_modules = cythonize(
        extensions, 
        annotate=annotate, 
        compiler_directives=directives,
    )
    setup(ext_modules=ext_modules)

    """
    #immediately remove build directory
    build_dir = "./build"
    if os.path.exists(build_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(build_dir)
    """
```

---

**Update #3:** Per the advice of @GZ0, there were lots of conditions where expressions in the code would evaluate to zero and be wastefully calculated. I have attempted to eliminate these areas with the following code (after fixing both the `case3` and `case6` statements):

```
cdef void cy_mktout_if(Vec4 *out, Vec4 *mean_mu_alpha, double[:, ::1] errors, double par_gamma) nogil:
    cdef:
        size_t i, n
        double[4] exp
        double exp_par_gamma
        double mu10, mu11, mu20, mu21
        double alpha1, alpha2
        bint j_is_larger
        double threshold2, threshold3
        bint case1, case2, case3, case4, case5, case6
        double t0, t1, t2
        double p12, p1, p2
        double t1_sum, t2_sum, p1_sum, p2_sum
        double c

    #compute the exp outside of the loop
    n = errors.shape[0]
    exp[0] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.a)
    exp[1] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.b)
    exp[2] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.c)
    exp[3] = cmath.exp(mean_mu_alpha.d)
    exp_par_gamma = cmath.exp(par_gamma)
    c = 168.0

    t1_sum = 0.0
    t2_sum = 0.0
    p1_sum = 0.0
    p2_sum = 0.0

    for i in range(n):
        mu10 = errors[i, 0] * exp[0]
        mu11 = exp_par_gamma * mu10
        mu20 = errors[i, 1] * exp[1]
        mu21 = exp_par_gamma * mu20
        alpha1 = errors[i, 2] * exp[2]
        alpha2 = errors[i, 3] * exp[3]

        j_is_larger = mu10 > mu20
        j_is_smaller = not j_is_larger
        threshold2 = (1 + mu10 * alpha1) / (c + alpha1)
        threshold3 = (1 + mu20 * alpha2) / (c + alpha2)

        if j_is_larger:
            case1 = mu10 < 1 / c
            case2 = mu21 >= threshold2
            case3 = not (case1 | case2)

            t0 = case1*c + case2 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) + case3 / threshold2
            t1 = case2 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1) + case3 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu10 - alpha1)
            t2 = c - t0 - t1

            t1_sum += t1
            t2_sum += t2
            p1_sum += case2 + case3
            p2_sum += case2

        else:
            case4 = mu20 < 1 / c
            case5 = mu11 >= threshold3
            case6 = not (case4 | case5)

            t0 = case4 * c + case5 * (c + alpha1 + alpha2) / (1 + mu11 * alpha1 + mu21 * alpha2) + case6 / threshold3
            t1 = case5 * (t0 * alpha1 * mu11 - alpha1)
            t2 = c - t0 - t1

            t1_sum += t1
            t2_sum += t2
            p1_sum += case5
            p2_sum += case5 + case6

    out.a = t1_sum/n
    out.b = t2_sum/n
    out.c = p1_sum/n
    out.d = p2_sum/n
```

For 10000 iterations, the current code performs as follows:

```
outer_loop: 0.5116949229995953 seconds
outer_loop_if: 0.617649456995423 seconds
mktout: 0.9221872320049442 seconds
mktout_if: 1.430276553001022 seconds
python: 10.116664300003322 seconds
```

I think the cost of the conditional and the branch misprediction that results is making the function surprisingly slower, but I would appreciate any help clearing this up for certain.

Comment: Good work. The original code was attempting to vectorize some conditional computations of `t0`, `t1`, and `t2` values under several different cases. Rewriting the function in C can actually make it a lot easier to implement that logic using explicit `if ... else ...` statements to avoid lots of unnecessary computations.

Comment: @GZ0 That's a good point, rewriting the logic should help even further. I am tempted to try that out and see the difference this makes!

Comment: By the way, there seems to be a mistake to use the xor operation in the original code for case 3 (compared with the commented version of the code). It should actually just be something like `j_is_larger and not (case1 or case2)`.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. if ... else ... (in the correct order) can really save the computations. However, I did that with python code. I should have tried Cython at that stage. Cython is really difficult to learn.

Comment: @Han Yuan I think the `numpy` version of the code still has room for some performance improvement, but definitely not at a magnitude comparable to a direct C implementation.

Comment: @GZ0 Interestingly, I just wrote up a conditional version of the code and it runs **slower**. Not sure if this is some sort of branch misprediction thing. Will post here shortly.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Were both functions tested using exactly the same input data? And were the tests done for different inputs? The performance of these functions might vary with different inputs. And if the error matrices in different runs were randomly generated with different seeds, the result could even vary in those runs.

Comment: @GZ0 I used the exact same test input for all of the cases, and the error matrices were fixed on all runs. I only tested the input provided in the initial question though, which uses a fixed random seed.I could try some different seeds to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @GZ0 Messing around with different seeds now as well as different values of mean_mu_alpha, but the difference appears pretty consistent.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon I see. Then you could be right that the computation reduction might not be enough to outweigh the branch misprediction overhead. Is it easy to time only the `if ... else` part of the code and compare it with the runtime of the corresponding code block in the other version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196091/discussion-between-codesurgeon-and-gz0).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon What i did with if statement is using elif to separate  6 cases. for example, threshold2 and all other computations can be avoided if it falls into case1 and t0 =168, t1=t2=0, p1=p2=0.

Comment: @HanYuan Could you post a screenshot of that code in the chatroom? We are running into a case where the if/else isn't providing any speed boost.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon I am a new user and cannot post in the chatroom.I upload it to an image hosting   https://i.loli.net/2019/07/07/5d2152506e57461261.png

Comment: @HanYuan Oh, I see. Didn't realize that the code was still from it was written in pure python. Can you upload it as a github gist maybe instead and send a link to that, and I can try to integrate it into the cython code?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon in the code, I avoided exp() here and there, so the conditions are slightly different from the code I posted here. also p1 p2 are not there (which are simply indicators of t1 t2 being positive)

Comment: @HanYuan Just translated the code you posted into cython. You can find it [in this github repo](https://github.com/AnishN/integration) under the `integrate_alt.pyx` file.

Comment: @HanYuan But it is particularly slow, rivaling the python version! The timings I get for 10000 iterations are as follows: `outer_loop_if: 0.5794296050007688
outer_loop: 0.32944605199736543
mktout_if: 1.1590596199966967
mktout: 0.6882156939973356
outer_loop_alt(mktout2): 1.9121688250015723
mktout2: 4.48448914400069
python: 7.4821989519987255`

Comment: @HanYuan Of course, the timing comparisons are not exactly fair since they are calculating slightly different results...

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Thanks a lot. I will read your code and let you know which method I settle on

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Please see the updates in the original question. Also you mentioned a small difference in returned numbers between you code and mine, this is probably due to the difference between > and >= in the conditions evaluations.

Comment: @HanYuan Great job. I updated the code in the aforementioned repo to include your full version as well. It looks like you were able to really optimize where everything was calculated in the loop. I get some different results though; I am not sure what is wrong with my computer! Here are my timings: `outer_loop_if: 0.47513486700017893
outer_loop: 0.2652342690000751
mktout_if: 1.061709786000165
mktout: 0.6509452919999603
outer_loop_alt(mktout2): 1.8044187640000473
mktout2: 4.275678849000087
mktout_full: 0.816135033999899
outer_loop_full: 0.26755886299997655
python: 6.939199279999912`