# No appreciable speed increase with Cython: How to handle NumPy broadcasting in Cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am a beginner to Cython. I am trying to speed up a function that is called many times, and a significant speed increase would be hugely helpful.

My original version of this function makes heavy use of NumPy broadcasting on large, multi-dimensional arrays. When attempting to Cythonize the function, I initially tried to convert these arrays to Cython memoryviews. However, I then came across compile errors, as the function performs arithmetic with these arrays, and I have since learnt that this is not supported by memoryviews.

As such, I modified my Cythonized code, to declare the arrays as NumPy ndarrays, rather than memoryviews. The Cythonized function now works, but does not yield any appreciable difference in speed compared to the original pure Python/NumPy version.

Therefore, I could now either: a.) Accept that this code is not amenable to being Cythonized, and look somewhere else for a way to increase speed, or b.) Revert to handling the large arrays as memoryviews, and somehow overcoming the arithmetic that needs to be performed.

To proceed with option b.), I wish to address the arithmetic in the for loop of this function. I could potentially write additional Cython functions that perform array multiplication and addition on an element-by-element basis, which I understand would then allow me to use memoryviews. However, given the complex NumPy broadcasting of this code, I expect this might involve significant effort (and I wouldn't necessarily know how to start...). Furthermore, I'm not certain whether this effort would bear fruit, given that doing things on an element-by-element basis (admittedly in C) may not actually be faster than the broadcast NumPy operations.

I would very much welcome any advice or support. Thank you.

```
from numpy import pi, exp, sin, cos
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=3] foo(bar, double dt, f, xi):
    cdef int nt, nh, nj
    cdef Py_ssize_t t

    nt = bar.shape[0]
    nh = bar.shape[1]

    if len(bar.shape) < 3:
        bar = bar[:, np.newaxis, :]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=3] bar_c = bar

    nj = len(f)
    k = (2 * pi * f) ** 2
    wn = k ** 0.5
    wd = (wn * (1 - xi ** 2) ** 0.5)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=3] u = np.zeros((nt, nj, nh))
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=3] v = np.zeros((nt, nj, nh))

    C1 = exp(-xi * wn * dt)
    C2 = sin(wd * dt)
    C3 = cos(wd * dt)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A11 = C1 * (C3 + (xi / (1 - xi ** 2) ** 0.5) * C2)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A12 = (C1 / wd) * C2
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A21 = (-wn / (1 - xi ** 2) ** 0.5) * C1 * C2
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] A22 = C1 * (C3 - (xi / (1 - xi ** 2) ** 0.5) * C2)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] B11 = C1 * (
        (((2 * xi ** 2 - 1) / (dt * wn ** 2)) + xi / wn) * C2 / wd
        + ((2 * xi / (dt * wn ** 3)) + (1 / wn ** 2)) * C3
    ) - 2 * xi / (dt * wn ** 3)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] B12 = (
        -C1
        * (
            ((2 * xi ** 2 - 1) / (dt * wn ** 2)) * C2 / wd
            + ((2 * xi) / (dt * wn ** 3)) * C3
        )
        - (1 / wn ** 2)
        + 2 * xi / (dt * wn ** 3)
    )
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] B21 = -A12 - ((A11 - 1) / (dt * wn ** 2))
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] B22 = -B21 - A12
    for t in range(0, nt - 1):
        u[t + 1, :, :] = (
            A11 * u[t, :, :]
            + A12 * v[t, :, :]
            + B11 * bar_c[t, :, :]
            + B12 * bar_c[t + 1, :, :]
        )
        v[t + 1, :, :] = (
            A21 * u[t, :, :]
            + A22 * v[t, :, :]
            + B21 * bar_c[t, :, :]
            + B22 * bar_c[t + 1, :, :]
        )

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=3] out = -2 * xi * wn * v - (wn ** 2) * u - bar_c
    return out
```

Apologies for not reducing the size of the code. Given the nature of the query, it is difficult for me to identify a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: `numpy` is already mostly C and Fortran. Cython helps to speed up mostly _pure Python_ computation. Where is that computation which you wanted to speed up? How did you find out that it's the part that slows you down, how did you profile your code?

Comment: @9000 - Thanks for your response. Those are good questions. I appreciate that NumPy is already fast, but given Cython's support for NumPy (and the existence of pages such as https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html), I thought that Cython would yield an additional speed increase - or at least be worth a try.
I profiled the code with cProfile, and also by simply adding time.time() requests are various points. The first part of the function is very fast in comparison to the "for" loop at the end: it is this "for" loop that I'm looking to speed up.

Comment: @Earthling. So if you want only the last loop to be profiled, please strip all unnecessary code and provide a [mcve], which means among other things: values of nj, nt, nh. `A11`&Co. don't need to be calculated - some random matrices will probably do (but because of cache effects one probably should use 8 different matrices).

Comment: The last loop does a ton of matrix multiplications using stuff like `u[t, :, :]`. Maybe it can indeed be improved by [declaring memoryviews for them](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html#efficient-indexing-with-memoryviews)? It would avoid much copying. You can also parallelize with `prange` once you got rid of copying to Python objects, see further down in the docs.

Comment: If you can avoid allocating memory for a  bunch of intermediate numpy arrays for calculations, then calculating the result element by element *can* lead to some significant savings. I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56899035/speed-up-an-integration-function-in-python/56910926#56910926) regarding this. I haven't looked through your code, but a lot of similar ideas likely apply here.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon and 9000 - Many thanks for your answers. The information you provided enabled me to modify the code to be more efficient. I will post an update in an edit to my original post.

Comment: Glad you found these comments helpful. Rather than editing your question to include your modified code, I would add your edit as answer instead and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @CodeSurgeon and @9000 for your answers. You had confirmed/suggested that, in some cases, C code could indeed give a speed increase over NumPy operations - even given the fact that Cython memoryviews require C operations to be performed on an element-by-element basis, and my original code was using NumPy operations broadcast over large arrays.

This prompted me to explore things further. Operating on memoryviews, on an element-by-element basis, the code is now between 3 ~ 40 times faster (strongly dependent on the size of the input arrays, which will vary).

The modifications basically look like this:

```
    # Memoryview declarations
    cdef double[:] u_mv = u
    cdef double[:] v_mv = v
    cdef double[:, :, :] out_mv = out
    cdef double[:, :, :] bar_mv = bar
    for j in range(nj):

        ...same calculation of constants C1, C2 etc. as before...

        for h in range(nh):
            for t in range(0, nt - 1):
                u_mv[t + 1] = (
                    A11 * u_mv[t]
                    + A12 * v_mv[t]
                    + B11 * bar_mv[t, 0, h]
                    + B12 * bar_mv[t + 1, 0, h]
                )
                v_mv[t + 1] = (
                    A21 * u_mv[t]
                    + A22 * v_mv[t]
                    + B21 * bar_mv[t, 0, h]
                    + B22 * bar_mv[t + 1, 0, h]
                )
                out_mv[t + 1, j, h] = (
                    -2 * xi_j * wn * v_mv[t + 1] - (wn ** 2) * u_mv[t + 1]
                    - bar_mv[t + 1, 0, h]
                )
            out_mv[0, j, h] = -bar_mv[0, 0, h]
    return out
```

Thanks again.